# How to Install tensorflow addons via conda

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I cannot find it out. Does Conda support it?

```
conda install tensorflow-addons
```

cannot find out the package

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find information related to TensorFlow Addons [here](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/07/introducing-tensorflow-addons.html.). Currently, it looks like Conda does not support Tensorflow Addons yet. You will have to wait for it to be implemented in the future. Otherwise, you can use `pip install tensorflow-addons`.

Comment: If I use pip in conda environment to have it installed, can I use it properly? Thanks

Comment: If you look through the link, it will depend on whether you have a Windows or Mac/Linux.

Comment: I see. 'in the futuer'.... So no support to Win at present.Thanks @RichardX

Answer (score 8):

You can use pip in your Anaconda environment to install tensorflow-addons.

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

then to use:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

I was able to successfully import it and use InstanceNormalization

Answer (score 5):

conda install -c esri tensorflow-addons

or

conda install -c esri/label/prerelease tensorflow-addons

https://anaconda.org/esri/tensorflow-addons

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest version of addons, run the following:

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

To use addons:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

For more information please refer the below link

[Tensorflow-addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons)