# “rasa init –no-prompt” returns NotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, tensorflow2.0, rasa, rasa-x

installed rasa successfully but when I try to create new project using

`rasa init --no-prompt`

I am getting this error

```
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\models.py:128 train_on_batch  *
    total_loss = self._total_batch_loss(batch_in)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\models.py:184 _total_batch_loss  *
    prediction_loss = self.batch_loss(batch_in)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\policies\ted_policy.py:594 batch_loss  *
    dialogue_embed, mask = self._emebed_dialogue(dialogue_in)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\policies\ted_policy.py:562 _emebed_dialogue  *
    dialogue_transformed = self._tf_layers["transformer"](
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:778 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\transformer.py:515 call  *
    x = layer(x, pad_mask=pad_mask, training=training)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:778 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\transformer.py:406 call  *
    ffn_out = layer(ffn_out, training=training)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:778 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\layers.py:88 call  *
    return super().call(inputs)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py:1146 call
    return self.activation(outputs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\activations\gelu.py:44 gelu
    return _activation_so.ops.addons_gelu(x, approximate)
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\utils\resource_loader.py:49 ops
    self._ops = tf.load_op_library(get_path_to_datafile(self.relative_path))
c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\load_library.py:57 load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)

NotFoundError: c:\users\azizul\anaconda3\envs\testr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\custom_ops\activations\_activation_ops.so not found
```

But I checked and `_activation_ops.so` exists in this directory.
Tried `rasa init --no-prompt --debug` but got the same error.

All the packages are installed in a anaconda environment. I used conda to install tensorflow but rasa is installed using pip. is this the reason? Here is what I did:

```
conda create --name tf_gpu
conda activate tf_gpu
conda install tensorflow-gpu
pip install rasa

rasa init --no-prompt
```

packages installed:

```
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.2.0                     eigen
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py37_0
aiofiles                  0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiohttp                   3.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
apscheduler               3.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0
astor                     0.8.0                    py37_0
async-generator           1.10                     pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blinker                   1.4                      py37_0
boto3                     1.12.12                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.15.12                  pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
cachetools                3.1.1                      py_0
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.14.0           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
colorclass                2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
coloredlogs               10.0                     pypi_0    pypi
colorhash                 1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              2.8              py37h7a1dbc1_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
dnspython                 1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
docopt                    0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
fbmessenger               6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
future                    0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    py37_0
gevent                    1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.11.2                     py_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2
google-pasta              0.1.8                      py_0
greenlet                  0.4.15                   pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.27.2           py37h351948d_0
h11                       0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
h2                        3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
hpack                     3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hstspreload               2020.2.29                pypi_0    pypi
httptools                 0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
httpx                     0.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
humanfriendly             8.0                      pypi_0    pypi
hyperframe                5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
importlib-metadata        1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2020.0                      166
jmespath                  0.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonpickle                1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
kafka-python              1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
kiwisolver                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
libprotobuf               3.11.4               h7bd577a_0
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0
matplotlib                3.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mattermostwrapper         2.2                      pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2020.0                      166
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0
multidict                 4.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37hc3f5095_1
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_4
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0
packaging                 19.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pika                      1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1
prompt-toolkit            2.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.11.4           py37h33f27b4_0
psycopg2-binary           2.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pydot                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py37_0
pykwalify                 1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pymongo                   3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.15.7                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
python-crfsuite           0.9.6                    pypi_0    pypi
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-engineio           3.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python-socketio           4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python-telegram-bot       11.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.3                      pypi_0    pypi
questionary               1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rasa                      1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rasa-sdk                  1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
redis                     3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
requests-toolbelt         0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3986                   1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
rocketchat-api            0.6.36                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.0                        py_0
ruamel-yaml               0.15.100                 pypi_0    pypi
s3transfer                0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sanic                     19.12.2                  pypi_0    pypi
sanic-cors                0.10.0.post3             pypi_0    pypi
sanic-jwt                 1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sanic-plugins-framework   0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.22.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9439919_0
setuptools                45.2.0                   py37_0
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0
sklearn-crfsuite          0.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
slackclient               2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy                1.3.13                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.31.1               he774522_0
tabulate                  0.8.6                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.1.0                     py3_0
tensorflow                2.1.0           eigen_py37hd727fc0_0
tensorflow-addons         0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           eigen_py37h49b2757_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0
tensorflow-hub            0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-probability    0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1
terminaltables            3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.31.1                   pypi_0    pypi
twilio                    6.26.3                   pypi_0    pypi
typeguard                 2.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tzlocal                   2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
wcwidth                   0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
webexteamssdk             1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websockets                8.1                      pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
yarl                      1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
```

Comment: There might be a conflict between pip & conda, or it might be your system set up - what OS are you on?  And what happens if you start a new conda env and don't install anything before installing rasa? Edit: Sorry I see from your paths you must be on windows.

Comment: See this answer about tensorflow-addons and conda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674901/how-to-install-tensorflow-addons-via-conda 
According to https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/07/introducing-tensorflow-addons.html pip-install for tensorflow addons might not be available for windows yet.

Comment: Solved. Actually I forgot to install VS build tool.

Comment: Great, could you put your comment as an answer and mark it the solution for anyone in the future looking at this q?

Comment: Have the same error. my environment: 
  Windows 10
  Anaconda
  Tensorflow-gpu==2.1
  Rasa==1.8.2

Installing Visual Studio 2019 community version seems fixed it